# What is the difference between Sub and a Function in Mapbasic?

Tags: mapbasic

In MapBasic it seems like Functions can have side effects so I don't really see the difference between using the following:

`Declare Sub MyProcedure (myParameter As String)` and then use `myParameter` after `Call MyProcedure(myParameter)`

or

`Declare Function MyProcedure () As string` and do something like `myParameter = MyProcedure()`

Am I missing something?

Comment: What side-effects? Otherwise yes, the 2 setups do the same. But using a function call is cleaner imho, in this case.

Comment: @UffeKousgaard a MapBasic function can modify state (of a global variable for instance) other than the return value. As described [on wikipedia on side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29)

Comment: OK, but so can Sub's. Global variables are truly global in Mapbasic. Not very modern in any sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `Function` always returns a value where as a `Sub` does not.   All methods in MAPBASIC can have side effects in the true term because it's not a functional language.

If you are expecting a return value you should use a `Function` that is what they are there for.

Can you modify the value of `myParameter` inside a `Sub` and then just use it after. Yes. But this is messy and generally not good programming

Sometimes modifying a input variable is a way to have multiple outputs in languages that support multiple return types (in something like Python you can return as many things as you want)

An example might be:

```
Declare Function Convert(passed as Boolean) As string

Function Convert(passed as Boolean) As string
   passed = True
   return "Converted"
End Function
```

Then you can check `passed` after running the function.

Comment: @peter-horsboll-moller might have to check my mapbasic knowledge there ;)

Comment: You passed, Nathan. Have you been reading your MapBasic reference guide again lately? :-)

Comment: And not that if you don't want your procedure to pass back a modified paramter, you can use the ByVal keyword

Answer (score 0):

Reading a bit more up on MapBasic I can see that one difference is that it is *not* possible to pause execution of a `Function` with `Stop` [according to the MapBasic user Guide](http://reference.mapinfo.com/software/mapbasic/english/12.0/MapBasicUserGuide.pdf#page=81&zoom=auto,0,240). But this restriction does not apply to `Sub`s.

Comment: Well, yeah. You are touching some of the not so good stuff in the MapBasic language - Debugging. I have been coding MapBasic applications for years and never ever used the debugging in MapBasic. I have basically learned to live with my own debug methods thru Print and Note statements